# In common lisp, is there any difference to create a vector using '#(...) or just #(...)?

Tags: arrays, vector, common-lisp

In Common Lisp (SBCL), it is possible to create vectors (arrays) using `'` before the `#` or not:

```lisp
CL-USER> '#(a b c)
#(A B C)

CL-USER> #(a b c)
#(A B C)
```

Apparently, they seem to generate the same object. After using `type-of` and `describe` on these expressions, they return identical information:

```lisp
CL-USER> (type-of #(a b c))
(SIMPLE-VECTOR 3)
CL-USER> (type-of '#(a b c))
(SIMPLE-VECTOR 3)
CL-USER> (describe #(a b c))
#(A B C)
  [simple-vector]

Element-type: T
Length: 3
; No value
CL-USER> (describe '#(a b c))
#(A B C)
  [simple-vector]

Element-type: T
Length: 3
; No value
```

Equality is also the same (with `equalp`):

```lisp
CL-USER> (equalp '#(a b c) #(a b c))
T
```

But differs wit `equal`:

```lisp
CL-USER> (equal '#(a b c) #(a b c))
NIL
```

The `'` is **not** the responsible for the above result being `NIL`:

```lisp
CL-USER> (equal '#(a b c) '#(a b c))
NIL
```

Is there any **practical** consequences of using one approach instead of the other when creating arrays?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### quoting

To clear any confusion, `'#(a b c)` starts with an apostrophe, which quotes a value; this is the same as having `(quote #(a b c))`. Quoting evaluates as the literal value being quoted.

```
CL-USER> '3
3
CL-USER> 'a
A
CL-USER> '#(a b c)
#(a b c)
```

#### literals

Generally, quoting an expression and evaluating it does not give the same value. For example:

```
CL-USER> (equalp '(vector 1) (vector 1))
NIL
```

Above, `'(vector 1)` evaluates as a list of two values (a symbol and a number), but `(vector 1)` as a vector of one element.

For literal values, however, they have the same value whether they are quoted or not:

```
CL-USER> (= '3 3)
T
```

The literal vector `#(a b c)` behaves the same, it is self-evaluating. When the form is read, the reader creates a vector object. Such an object evaluates as itself:

```
CL-USER> (eval #(a b c))
#(a b c)
```

#### equal

The use of `equal` can be surprising here, but the result is consistent with the definition:

> Two arrays are equal only if they are eq, with one exception: strings and bit vectors are compared element-by-element (using eql).

Here you don't manipulate strings or bit-vectors, so you only test for identity, as-if you used `EQ`. But you have two different instances of the vector, once quoted, once not quoted, and they are likely to be two distinct vectors (but `EQ` (and so, `EQUAL` too) could be T with a different compiler).

#### conclusion

> Is there any practical consequences of using one approach instead of the other when creating arrays?

I don't think so, you generally don't quote numbers, the same goes for array literals.

**NB. as for all literal values, you should not mutate them, they are constant values.**